# css max-width not working inside another div

Tags: css

See css/html below; Can someone help why the max-width in the inside div (class "b") will not work? I'm running this in chrome and it stays with the max-width of 600px and does not adjust to 400px. The outside div works and adjusts itself from 800 to 600 when adjusting the browser window but the inside div stays on 600px! any tips? I tried adding !important and other things but nothing helped.

Thanks!

```css
.a{
margin: 0 auto;
background:yellow;
max-width:800px;
min-width:600px;
height:100px;

}
.b{
margin: 0 auto;
background:green;
max-width:600px;
min-width:400px;
height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
<div class="b">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Everything looks like it's working correctly.  Elements with `display:block` (divs have this by default) will always expand to cover the largest width they can.

Comment: `a` makes it so that the parent element already has a min width of 600px. Since the parent is already 600px, `b` will take up all the space.

Comment: Do you want to put a left and right margin on div.b of 100px? That would seem to fix it.

Comment: When you make the browser window smaller than 600px the scond div should get smaller until you reach 400px but that doesn't happen

Comment: look at @karaokyo answer

Comment: OP you are wrong if outer container is min 600px then the child it's always that value too doesn't scale with the window ....

Comment: but how come the child doesnt get the max-width?

Comment: the max-width of the parent is 800 and the child has the 600

Comment: Is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/x3wog14r/?

Comment: Thanks! margin will do it too. It's just weird that with max-width it doesn't adjust at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outside div is wrong. Because `a` `max-width:600px;` the browser stoped that `max-width` you must give equal or lower value from `.b`

```
.a{
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:yellow;
    max-width:800px;
    min-width:400px;
    height:100px;

}
.b{
    margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
    background:green;
    min-width:400px;
    height:50px;
}
```

working [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/azYdwK)

Comment: I just tried your css above but it still does not adjust. the .b should get adjusted to 300px but it doesnt it just stays at 600px

Comment: It is working for me!! I updated my answer there is a demo now. please check it

Comment: Thanks for the demo! but it's still not working; when you adjust the browser to 600px the green div covers all the way the yellow div. if it would've adjust like I want even at 600px you shuold still see the yellow sticking out because the green div should become smaller

Comment: Which browser you are using ?

Comment: I don't understand why it is not working for you. There is no problem for me :/

Comment: Please see screenshot: http://i1381.photobucket.com/albums/ah202/mayerfri/Untitled_zps9zibtwvr.png

you can see that the screen is 600px and the green div did not adjust anything smaller

Comment: check demo again please

Comment: now we getting somewhere thanks! I see you added margin to the left-right. but I guess max-width does not work in this situation.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm sorry I tried to do it before but its telling me -vote up requires 15 reputation - hopefully I'll have 15 soon and I'll come back to upvote