# Max width not working for div created for Google Adsense ad

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set up a div for Google Adsense inside another div. The code is as follows,

```
<div id="content">
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
<p>Paragraph 4</p>
<div id="banner">
<!--google adsense code here-->
</div>
<p>Paragraph 5</p>
<p>Paragraph 6</p>
<p>Paragraph 7</p>
</div>
```

The CSS is

```
#content {
max-width: 40em;
}

#banner {
max-width:50%;
float:left;
}
```

When I run this code, I don't see the adsense ad at all. There is a slight indentation at the beginning of paragraph 5. Looks like the ad is hiding somewhere. When I check the console tab in the browser (inspect element) I see this error,

> TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: No slot size for availableWidth=0

However if I replace `max-width` to `width` for `banner` as

```
#banner {
width:50%;
float:left;
}
```

the ad runs. However the paragraph on the right of the ad and the ad itself are not properly responsive especially when I re-size the browser after loading the page. I want to use `max-width` property. What am I missing?

The QA [css max-width not working inside another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570395/css-max-width-not-working-inside-another-div) didn't help me much.

Comment: The error message suggests that AdSense seems to have a problem with your container having 0 width, as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zdsd8404/1/). What dimensions should the used banners have? As a start, you could try to remove the `float: left;`, so your `#banner` will actually be 50% of its parent in width.

Comment: You will need to use media queries: set different width depending on screen size. However the adsense ad will maintain the same size after page load so you must make sure that the paragraph does not go below the ad.

Comment: @SalmanA I am already using media queries. Even if I wasn't using media queries, the layout should work.

@CedricReichenbach I want the container to be 50% of the div content. Perhaps adsense is not able to determine the width for the `max-width` property. Removing the `float` property doesn't work.

Adding a <p> or <h> or something inside `banner` makes it work with `max-width` property as seen here http://jsfiddle.net/zdsd8404/2/, even with `float` property. But not sure why it doesn't work with adsense code. The <p> appears but not the ad below it.

Comment: @Justin float+max-width means the container has no initial width and it will grow upto max width depending on content. AdSense code, apparently, wants to know the width in advance in order to select best-fit ad. It like browser wants to know ad width to determine `#banner` width and ad wants to know `#banner` width to determine its own width. Not gonna work.

Comment: @SalmanA I guess that's why the ad is now showing up. Adsense needs to know the definite width. So I guess, I have to settle with `width` property. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is a result of placing a responsive ad into a floated box which has no initial width prior to inserting the ad.

Adsense's responsive code is for use when you want the ad to be sized according to the parent element, *not the other way around*.  If you want to pick a certain ad size, and have the parent block sized according to that ad, then you need to use a non-responsive code (or use the variant of the responsive code where you specify the width and height using media queries).

When the page loads, the Adsense ad is not there yet, it's just an empty placeholder `<ins>` element.  The Adsense responsive code checks the width of the parent element to that placeholder, and uses that width to determine which ad to insert.

The problem is, while most divs will default to filling the full width of their parent element even when they're empty, a float won't.  An empty float will have zero width.  So when the Adsense responsive code loads it doesn't have any way of determining what sized ad it should use, as the parent element it appears in has a zero width.

You'll need to give the floated element some particular width, such as `width: 50%`, or you need to specify the size of the Adsense ad by using non-responsive ad code or using the variant of the responsive ad code where you specify the size of the ad with media queries.